# How to change the size of Images on category page in magento 2 from admin panel

Tags: magento

i want to resize the image size on the category page. I have made changes in the category page, shows 3 images instead of 4. But the image size is still the same. I want to increase it by admin panel, not to change the code manually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without customizing a lot of stuff first. Image sizes are set in your theme in `/app/design/frontend/YOURVENDORNAME/YOURTHEMENAME/etc/view.xml`